# Floating point precision in MariaDB using python mysql connector

Tags: python, mysql, floating-point, connector

I am new to python & MariaDB and wonder that all float types in all my MariaDB tables lack precision. Here's an example: I create a table in MariaDB with four different data types float, double, decimal and int:

```
CREATE TABLE test(
   id INT,
   foo float,
   bar double,
   foo2 decimal(19,5),
   bar2 int,
   PRIMARY KEY( id )
)
```

Now I insert and read out the same number (1234567.891) in each field:

```
cx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='ABC',
                                         host='192.168.0.107',
                                         database='DEF')
query= "INSERT INTO test (foo, bar, foo2, bar2) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"
writtenvalues = (1234567.891, 1234567.891, 1234567.891, 1234567.891)
csr = cx.cursor()
csr.execute(query, writtenvalues)
cx.commit()
query= "SELECT * FROM test"
csr.execute(query)
readvalues = csr.fetchall()
print(readvalues)
csr.close()
cx.close()
```

I get the following result:

```
[(0, 1234570.0, 1234567.891, Decimal('1234567.89100'), 1234568)]
```

I am surprised that the first number (foo) which is supposed to be a float comes out as 1234570.0 (rounded up to the next 10!). It is even less accurate than the integer (bar2). Only the double type is accurate.
Is there a simple way to improve the precision of the float-type, or do I need to change them all to double?

Comment: There is no way to improve the precision of `float`. It is what it is, about 7 or 8 significant decimal digits. Also be aware that a Python `float` corresponds to a database `double`.

Comment: @ BoarGules: Thanks for the clear answer. I'll swich my database to double then and recalculate...